# Swift pan gesture movement constraints

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to keep my UILabel from moving down below `CONTROLTOPOFFSET`.

```
CONTROLTOPOFFSET = (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - CONTROLSIZE) - CONTROLPAD
```

I'm using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and would like to run the check within this function, just not sure how.

```
func moveScore(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let tranlation: CGPoint = gesture.translationInView(boardView)
        gesture.view?.center = CGPointMake(gesture.view!.center.x +   tranlation.x, gesture.view!.center.y + tranlation.y)


    gesture.setTranslation(CGPointMake(0, 0), inView: boardView) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this question without knowing much about your view hierarchy. Assuming that your view hierarchy is simply the view from a view controller with the board view as a subview which has a label as a subview,

```
<UIWindow: 0x7fdf5c8157e0; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fdf5c816ba0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fdf5c814950>>
   | <UIView: 0x7fdf5c91ec40; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdf5c91eda0>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x7fdf5ad11380; frame = (107 268; 200 200); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdf5ad10aa0>>
   |    | <UILabel: 0x7fdf5c91c280; frame = (209 464.333; 42 21); text = 'Label'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fdf5c922850>; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdf5c91c670>>
```

You could do something like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var boardView: UIView!

  var CONTROLTOPOFFSET : CGFloat {
    get {
      let CONTROLSIZE : CGFloat = 200.0
      let CONTROLPAD : CGFloat = 10.0
      return (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - CONTROLSIZE) - CONTROLPAD
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: "moveScore:")
    label.userInteractionEnabled = true
    label.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
  }

  func moveScore(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let tranlation: CGPoint = gesture.translationInView(view)
    let newPosition = CGPointMake(gesture.view!.center.x + tranlation.x, gesture.view!.center.y + tranlation.y)
    if newPosition.y < CONTROLTOPOFFSET {
      gesture.view?.center = newPosition
      gesture.setTranslation(CGPointMake(0, 0), inView: view)
    }

  }

}
```

The difference is that the translation is done with respect to the superview which is the one that is use for your `CONTROLTOPOFFSET` and there is an if statement to prevent further movement beyond the bounds.

I'm sure your view hierarchy is a lot more complex that the one from the example but hopefully you can extrapolate the example to your code.